# Avoid page vertical re-alignment when clicking a hyperlink

Tags: hyperref, links

I am using hyperlinks in a latex text (specifically with `hyperref` and `cleveref`).
Usually I read pdf at a zoom >100% to eliminate white borders from the displayed part; but when I click on a hyperlink the alignments gets messed up as the redirect tries to place the linked element on the leftmost side of the page. This is particularly annoying when I click at an equation hyperlink, as I keep the numbering on the rightmost side of the page.

How can I suppress the vertical re-alignment when clicking on a link?

If you want to try it yourself, here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{here}
0=0
\end{equation}

\eqref{here}

\end{document}
```

---

In https://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html I have found the option
`pdfview` which should do the job. It is stated that it takes three values XYZ which respectively indicate the position (left, top) and the zoom at which the links should work.
However I'm unable to use them as

```
\usepackage[pdfview={XYZ 12 123 1234}]{hyperref}
```

doesn't do anything... How should I pass the value to `pdfview`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: i believe this is a function of the pdf reader, and that it can't be controlled from within latex.  (i would be very happy to be proved wrong!)

Comment: @barbarabeeton in that case, could i place the mark to which the link points on the leftmost side of the page?

Comment: @Quoniam -- specifying the option `\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}` will place the equation numbers on the left side of the page.